# How can I change my username on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, users, display-names

I read a reply from Stack Overflow, and I find the replier showing his name instead of @user999999 format. Below is one of the message I got from my question. @user3059850 is my username and ezanker is the replier name.

> @user3059850, anytime you add widgets dynamically after the page is already created, jQM does not automatically initialize and enhance, so you need to do it in script. –  ezanker 10 hours ago

How can I change my username @user3059850 to my desired name?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Click on profile on upper right corner. Click edit. Change "Display Name" to desired. Save

**This answer is now obsolete!** Please refer to any of the other answers which explain how to do this in modern versions of the site.

Comment: Choose wisely, though, because if you make a mistake, you can't change it again for 30 days. (I think there might be a short grace period where you can change it to correct a mistake, but I'm not 100% certain.)

Comment: Can't see the profile on upper right corner, could give me the URL?

Comment: For you its: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3059850/user3059850

Comment: бдительность, do you mind referring the screen capture from http://screencloud.net/v/hc5h , I could not see the profile on upper right corner but only the network profile. After I click into the network profile, I could not find the Dispaly Name (screen capture of network profile http://screencloud.net/v/DUBJ ).

Comment: бдительность, I click the link "click here to edit" under (your about me is currently blank) and I can change my Display Name. Many thanks.

Answer (score 19):

There's now a different navigation path.  After you click on your profile link in the upper right, there is a tab called "Edit Profile & Settings."

[image]

The url seems to be of the format:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/{internal user id}
```

Comment: also, one of the option in the profile settings is to use Gravatar. If you have a gravatar.com account you can link it and Stack'll pick up changes from there.

Comment: This shouldn't be so difficult. I should just see and edit link or an edit icon right next to my image so that I can quickly and easily change my photo. I'm amazed that this hasn't been done yet.

Answer (score 15):

***Change Display name:***

***1. Users -> 2.  Edit profile and settings ->  3.Change Display name***

[image]

[image]

**For changing picture**

***1. Users -> 2.  Edit profile and settings -> 3. Change picture***

[image]

Comment: First answer on this question with freehand circles!

Comment: @RocketNikita ..but.. they're blue. Not red :O

Comment: @Scratte Does this matter?

Comment: @RocketNikita No :) But see [Where did freehand circles originate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385865/where-did-freehand-circles-originate) :)