# Change Stack Overflow Profile Picture

Tags: discussion

All I want to do is to change my profile picture. Is it even possible?

How would I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/5075227

Comment: As a user (per 26 Feb 21), I found it hard to find it without reading this guidance. Hopefully it will be easily spot-able in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can change your Picture. Go To: Your Profile -> Edit Profile and Settings, then you can click on change Picture.

Comment: you can also link it to your Gravatar.com account and it'll pick that one up.  I had forgotten that I did that and spent 10 mins figuring it out :-P

Comment: There is no option as change Picture under Settings tab

Comment: There is no option to "Edit Profile and Settings". This shouldn't be so difficult. I should just see and edit link or an edit icon right next to my image so that I can quickly and easily change my photo. I'm amazed that this hasn't been done yet.

Comment: Where is "your profile".

Comment: Still no answer in 2020?

Comment: You can go to this url https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/<your_user_id>

Comment: It's like it's not possible until you reach certain level. I tried all I can bụ could not see that on my profile. If it's figured out please drop comment let us know.

Comment: Make sure you're not on the Stack Exchange site. You have to be in Stack Overflow

Comment: I was able to locate my user page by going to stackoverflow.com/users and then in the filter by user box at the top, I searched for my username.  

Then I clicked on my username, and selected "Edit profile and settings" like others already mentioned.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I was having trouble with this also, then noticed that on the Edit Profile and Settings page, after uploading a new photo, I had to scroll down to see the 'Save' button.  Once I clicked that my picture was updated.

Comment: Change Profile picture (latest anwer)-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268879/how-can-i-change-my-username-on-stack-overflow/405881#405881

Comment: When you login with Facebook/Google/Other third party sign in method you cannot see "Edit Profile and Settings", So sign out and enter with Email and Password and now you can see "Edit Profile and Settings" and change your profile picture.

Comment: Didn't work. Still couldn't find answer for this, any tips?