# Where did freehand circles originate?

Tags: discussion, meta

I've seen a lot of comments on Meta about freehand circles/the lack of, and I'm wondering where they originated.

What post first included (or mentioned) them? How did they take on?

```
   _________
 _/ freehand \
| circles?   |
 \__________/
```

Comment: Cross dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/292385

Comment: Don't think you are getting downvotes because the topic is not intresting or lack of research. You are getting downvotes because your *ascii freehand circle* is bad ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif Darn.

Comment: @TemaniAfif How's this look?

Comment: worse -.- (:p) ... there is rules to draw a perfect freehand circle: it should be red, have a thickness of 2.145962px, you should not blink or breath while drawing it, it should be a continuous line (no way for the bug to get outside of it) and most important: it should never look like it's a circle!

Comment: @TemaniAfif At this point, would it just be better to remove my attempts?

Comment: You are free to do what you want. The comment was more a *joke* than a serious one ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the early days of Stack Overflow, there were a lot of bugs. When reporting bugs, it's helpful to identify the bug that's being reported. For visual bugs, that can mean taking a screenshot of a page where the bug appears and then directing the viewer's attention to a specific area of the page... A red circle works pretty well for this.

But! Who among us can draw a perfect circle? *Witches*, that's who. And maybe other creatures of the night. And, of course, folks who cheat and use the built-in circle tool in their fancy graphics editors. The rest of us honest folk tend to produce wobbly stuff like this:

> [image: wobbly circle]

...thus, a free-hand circle is a good proof of one's bonafides. Don't post a bug report without one!

#### See also:

- [bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/bug/info)
- [the meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775)
- [Freehand Circles Drawing Tool](https://stackapps.com/questions/6353/freehand-circles-drawing-tool)

Comment: The Freehand Circles Drawing Tool isn't working! We're all doomed!