# Bug in CSS code of badges tiles

Tags: bug, design

Don't know they are called *tiles* or whatever, but I refer to this.

I'm new to CSS, but I guess this is a [very rookie bug, ahahah.](https://tfln.co/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/giphy-2-1.gif)

Considering that the problem does not occur [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/157/functional-programming), where the same plate (better than tile?) is shown, I guess there are some reusability issues in the code.

[image]

Comment: -1 (Not really) for not using freehand red circles¬

Comment: @Paulie_D, what are _freehand red circles_??? (And I +1 your comment!)

Comment: [Freehand Circles1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/163529) , [Freehand Circles2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385866/965146)

Comment: Guess it'll take about 6 to 8 weeks for @Enlico to add freehand circles...

Comment: @10Rep what does that mean? :D

Comment: @Enlico [6 to 8 weeks meme on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/500111) :)

Comment: Oh, come on, let's not unfocus from the fact that the site has bugs :P

Comment: The community is upvoting your meta post, so they know that it is actually a bug. The comments are just as a joke :).

Comment: I didn't get one, ahahah. Anyway, yeah, I'm becoming famous, I believe, ahahah.

Comment: they are missing overflow:hidden there

Comment: No, why should they cut the text out?

Comment: so what should they do? (1) cut the text (2) shrink the date (3) keep the overflow (4) rework the whole page to have more space for some specific tags

Comment: More space. Space to accommodate the longest tag.

Comment: @TemaniAfif - removing `max-width` works well regardless of viewport size - not sure what you are talking about (but I may be missing something, you're the SME)?

Comment: In my opinion, obviously.

Comment: @OlegValter removing the max-width will get you the (2) shrink the date: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDnoF.png

Comment: @TemaniAfif - thank you, I expected something like that. But can't a `flex-wrap: wrap;` be added to the container's styles to move the date downwards instead? https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtAAD.png

Comment: @SebastianSimon - why are we closing the question against a question without any non-deleted answer?  I am an interested party, though, but still... Aren't duplicate closure supposed to ignore time in favour of actual answers?

Comment: [reported again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368273/786798) today on MSE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to wait for 6 to 8 weeks until this is resolved. In the meantime, you can take solace in the fact that this is fixable. Below are several potential approaches to how this issue could be mitigated - choose your poison.

---

**1. Remove max-width restriction**

The following rulesets reset the `max-width` rule on the element and move the grid cell with the date downwards in case of a very long tag name (up to the current maximum of 35 characters) via the `flex-wrap` rule:

```css
.profile-badges .badge-tag {
    max-width: unset;
}

.profile-badges .grid {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

This is how the result looks like (the badge could be stretched to fill the row, but it is omitted for the sake of consistency with how normal badges look like):

[image: max-width and flex-wrap solution screenshot]

---

**2. Use a userscript**

The following is a script for hiding the overflow characters with `overflow: hidden` and making the badge expandable on hover. Of course, everything done by the script could be also done in pure CSS (coming soon).

Credit for the initial idea goes to [Scratte](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/12695027/scratte):

> Moving the date is not a good idea. Overlay is better :) Hide the darn thing behind the date.

The following is a preview of the script (see the source and minified distribution below):

[image: preview of the script]

TypeScript source:

```ts
interface MouseEvent extends Event {
  readonly target: HTMLElement;
}

interface Document
  extends Node,
    DocumentAndElementEventHandlers,
    DocumentOrShadowRoot,
    GlobalEventHandlers,
    NonElementParentNode,
    ParentNode,
    XPathEvaluatorBase {
  getElementsByClassName<T extends Element>(
    classNames: string
  ): HTMLCollectionOf<T>;
}

((_w, d) => {
  const grid_cell = ".grid--cell";
  const badge_tag = "badge-tag";

  const badges = [...d.getElementsByClassName<HTMLElement>(badge_tag)];

  const toggleOverflow = (
    { style: columnStyle }: HTMLElement,
    { style: badgeStyle }: HTMLElement,
    state: "on" | "off"
  ) => {
    const isOn = state === "on";

    badgeStyle.overflow = isOn ? "hidden" : "unset";
    //@see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20566810/11407695
    badgeStyle.verticalAlign = isOn ? "bottom" : "unset";
    badgeStyle.maxWidth = isOn ? "150px" : "unset";
    columnStyle.zIndex = isOn ? "unset" : "2";
  };

  const getBadgeItem = (badge: HTMLElement) =>
    badge.classList.contains(badge_tag) &&
    badge.closest<HTMLElement>(grid_cell);

  badges.forEach((badge) => {
    const badgeitem = badge.closest<HTMLElement>(grid_cell);
    if (!badgeitem) return;
    const { nextElementSibling: dateitem } = badgeitem;
    if (!dateitem) return;

    (dateitem as HTMLElement).style.zIndex = "1";
    badgeitem.style.maxWidth = "50%";

    toggleOverflow(badgeitem, badge, "on");
  });

  d.addEventListener("mouseover", ({ target }) => {
    const badgeitem = getBadgeItem(target);
    badgeitem && toggleOverflow(badgeitem, target, "off");
  });

  d.addEventListener("mouseout", ({ target }) => {
    const badgeitem = getBadgeItem(target);
    badgeitem && toggleOverflow(badgeitem, target, "on");
  });
})(window, document);
```

Minified JavaScript (polyfill for `closest` not included):

```js
"use strict";var __read=this&&this.__read||function(t,e){var n="function"==typeof Symbol&&t[Symbol.iterator];if(!n)return t;var r,o,a=n.call(t),i=[];try{for(;(void 0===e||0<e--)&&!(r=a.next()).done;)i.push(r.value)}catch(t){o={error:t}}finally{try{r&&!r.done&&(n=a.return)&&n.call(a)}finally{if(o)throw o.error}}return i},__spread=this&&this.__spread||function(){for(var t=[],e=0;e<arguments.length;e++)t=t.concat(__read(arguments[e]));return t};!function(t){function r(t,e,n){t=t.style,e=e.style,n="on"===n,e.overflow=n?"hidden":"unset",e.verticalAlign=n?"bottom":"unset",e.maxWidth=n?"150px":"unset",t.zIndex=n?"unset":"2"}function n(t){return t.classList.contains(e)&&t.closest(o)}var o=".grid--cell",e="badge-tag",a=__spread(t.getElementsByClassName(e));a.forEach(function(t){var e,n=t.closest(o);!n||(e=n.nextElementSibling)&&(e.style.zIndex="1",n.style.maxWidth="50%",r(n,t,"on"))}),t.addEventListener("mouseover",function(t){var e=t.target,t=n(e);t&&r(t,e,"off")}),t.addEventListener("mouseout",function(t){var e=t.target,t=n(e);t&&r(t,e,"on")})}((window,document));
```